# MySQL Select Record Within Last 4 Hours

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a last_post_time field set up as DATETIME in my user database. I want to check if the current user has a successful post made in the last 4 hours in my PHP file, and if not, do something. Here is what I have:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT last_post_time FROM xxyyzz_users WHERE ID=$user_ID");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$userpost = $row[last_post_time];

if ($userpost == '') { // no post, do this } else { // has a post, do this }
```

1) How do I add the post time check to my query

2) Is my PHP correct?

Comment: $userpost in hour ? whats the format of it

Comment: Refer to: [*DATE_ADD*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#idm48001801791296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only those users directly in your query and return the number of users meeting that criteria

```
SELECT count(*) as u_count
FROM xxyyzz_users 
WHERE ID=$user_ID
and now() - interval 4 hour <= last_post_time
```

Comment: OP: If you've never used `INTERVAL` before, it's good to note that it's `4 hour` and not `4 hours`. (the same goes for `minute`, `second`, `day` etc.)

Comment: @juregen d: should be <= last_post_time

Comment: @gview: Actually not.

Comment: @juregen: He said he wanted to know if a post was made in the last 4 hours. Your query finds rows OLDER than 4 hours.